# Exim config - no external connections, only localhost connections (Linux)

Tags: linux, centos, exim, configuration

CentOS running Exim 4.63(inc latest fixes).

I want to configure exim to not listen on the external IP, only localhost so that exim can only be used from the server itself (no remote connections).

What's the config option for this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option you want is `local_interfaces` in the main part of the configuration.  [Section 13.1 of the spec](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch13.html#SECID89) gives some examples, and the full definitions of the option is in the [alphabetical list of main options](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html#SECTalomo) (which I can't directly link to because it doesn't have an anchor).

To summarize:

```
local_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

define interface parameter under transport section to localhost in main co

Comment: Tried this in the transports sectio of exim.conf and restarted exim and I'm still able to connect remotely:
<code>
remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  interface = 127.0.0.1</code>

Comment: This is wrong, the interface optoin sets the IP for outgoing connections